# React-Final-Form how to pass props location.search to function

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I've been using React-Final-Form for the last few days but I have a lot of issues.

In my main function, PasswordReset, I need the take the prop 'location.search' and pass it to the custom 'handleSubmitOnClick' in order to handle the outcome on submit.

Here the main function:

```
const handleSubmitOnClick = ({ // I need the location.search to be passed here as prop
  password,
  password_confirmation,
}) => {

  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/passwords';

  const headers = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
  }

  const data = {
    "user": {
      "reset_password_token": location.search,
      "password": password,
      "password_confirmation": password_confirmation,
    }
  }

  axios.post(url, data, headers)
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error)))
}

const PasswordReset = ({
  location //<==== I need to pass this to 'handleSubmitOnClick' function
}) => 
  <Fragment>
    <h1>Password Reset page</h1>

    <Form 
      onSubmit={handleSubmitOnClick}
      decorators={[focusOnError]}
    >
      {
        ({ 
          handleSubmit, 
          values, 
          submitting,
        }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>         

          <Field 
            name='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            validate={required}
          >
            {({ input, meta, placeholder }) => (
              <div className={meta.active ? 'active' : ''}>
                <label>{placeholder}</label>
                <input {...input} 
                  type='password' 
                  placeholder={placeholder} 
                  className="signup-field-input"

                />
                {meta.error && meta.touched && <span className="invalid">{meta.error}</span>}
                {meta.valid && meta.dirty && <span className="valid">Great!</span>}
              </div>
            )}
          </Field>

          <Field 
            name='password_confirmation'
            placeholder='Confirm password'
            validate={required}
          >
            {({ input, meta, placeholder }) => (
              <div className={meta.active ? 'active' : ''}>
                <label>{placeholder}</label>
                <input {...input} 
                  type='password' 
                  placeholder={placeholder} 
                  className="signup-field-input"

                />
                {meta.error && meta.touched && <span className="invalid">{meta.error}</span>}
                {meta.valid && meta.dirty && <span className="valid">Great!</span>}
              </div>
            )}
          </Field>

          <button 
            type="submit"
            className="signup-button"
            disabled={submitting}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Form>
  </Fragment>

export default PasswordReset;
```

Any help is REALLY appreciated. A bad answer is better than no answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can curry your function to have `location` updated everytime.

**Currying method:** (preferred by linters)

```
const handleSubmitOnClick = (location) => ({ //location would come from PasswordReset every time there's a re-render
                             ^^^^^^^^
  password,
  password_confirmation,
}) => {
   ...
}

const PasswordReset = ({
  location //<==== I need to pass this to 'handleSubmitOnClick' function
}) => 
  <Fragment>
    <h1>Password Reset page</h1>

    <Form 
      onSubmit={handleSubmitOnClick(location)} // <--- This will update location on every re-render
      decorators={[focusOnError]}
    >
      { ... }
    </Form>
  </Fragment>

export default PasswordReset;
```

**Inline function method:**

Alternatively you can use what other answer provided but you still need to update your `handleSubmitOnClick` function to accept your `location` prop. It will create new function on every re-render, but because inline functions are ***bad practice*** deemed by linters I prefer currying method.

```
   <Form 
      onSubmit={() => handleSubmitOnClick(location)} // <--- This will create new function on every re-render
      decorators={[focusOnError]}
    >
```

Comment: That's what currying would do, it will update the function with new location on every render, similar to your answer where you are creating new function instead on every render.

Comment: Did the trick. My mistake was to put location inside the handleSubmitClick deconstructed area, where the values are.

Comment: Hey Rikin, would you be able (or anyone else) to look at this issue I've been fighting with for weeks? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015594/issue-to-submit-csv-file-to-db-via-post-axios-react-final-form   .... any solution is much appreaciated. I've tried dataForm, I've tried new Blob .. always returning tons of errors

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form 
  onSubmit={() => handleSubmitOnClick(location)}
  decorators={[focusOnError]}
>
```

Wrap it in an anonymous function that once called, calls your function with the required param, which would be `location` in this case.

After that the function would have an extra argument:

```
handleSubmitOnClick = location => ({..props})
```

Comment: `handleSubmitOnClick` does not accept `location` rather destructures `password` and `password_confirmation` thus it need to be updated as well, this aint the complete solution (yet)

Comment: so then update the handleSubmitOnClick function to accept location..?

Comment: Yep, that is what you were missing for complete solution.